# How to create a batch file to write the folder name in a text file inside each folder

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a few hundred folders that I will be renaming, but I want a way to know what the original folder was called. So I am trying to create a batch file that will look at the current folder name, then create a text file in that folder with the name "Original.txt"

My attempts at using the command (`cd > original.txt`) work one-by-one, once I'm in each folder, but I'd rather do it one level higher and have it apply to all folders in the containing folder.

As an example:

```
Books\

Books\Book1\

Books\Book2\

Books\Book3\

Books\Book4\

Books\Book5\
```

I'd like to have each Book# folder create an "Original.txt" file with "Book#" in it (`Books\Book1\`'s "Original.txt" file would contain "Book1")

Id like to run the batch file at the "Books" level not having to go to each `Book1`, `Book2`, etc and run `CD > Original.txt`

My attempts at this have just written an "Original.txt" file a few hundred times at the Books level with only Books.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy, use the `for /d` command:

```
cd C:\...\Books
for /d %%a in (*) do (Echo %%~fa > %%~fa\Original.txt)
```

And that should do your job for you.

Mona.

Comment: @Marichyasana This code is meant for a batch file, not cmd. If you want to run this in cmd, use only one `%` instead of `%%`. If you do not have knowledge in batch please do not simply vote down answer which may be correct.

Comment: Thank you, looks like this worked perfectly, and completed what would have taken me hours in a matter of seconds!

Comment: @user3040104: If you found this useful, please make the answer correct

Answer (score -2):

Easy bro

```
@echo off
for /r %%a in (.) do (pushd "%%a"&cd>Original.txt)
cls&echo/Done.
```

Just save this .bat in the "Books" folder

Comment: Any reason to use `pushd`? That seems like an odd way to accomplish this. You might also want to `pushd` back to the original directory.